# Create self signed certificate with subjectAltName to fix [missing_subjectAltName] in Chrome 58+

Tags: ssl, certificate, openssl

I'm trying to create a self signed certificate for `localhost` containing `subjectAltName` to satisfy Chrome 58+:

`createcertificate.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
filename="$1server"
openssl req -new -sha256 -nodes -out ./../nginx/ssl/${filename}.csr -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout ./../nginx/ssl/${filename}.key -config <( cat ${filename}_csr.txt )
openssl x509 -req -in ./../nginx/ssl/${filename}.csr -CA ~/ssl/rootCA.pem -CAkey ~/ssl/rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out ./../nginx/ssl/${filename}.crt -days 500 -sha256
```

`server_csr.txt`:

```
[req]
default_bits = 2048
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
req_extensions = req_ext
distinguished_name = dn

[ dn ]
C=US
ST=New York
L=Rochester
O=End Point
OU=Testing Domain
emailAddress=your-administrative-address@your-awesome-existing-domain.com
CN = localhost

[ req_ext ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[ alt_names ]
DNS.1 = localhost
```

Call `./createcertificate.sh`:

```
server_csr.txt
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
.........................................................................................................+++
...............................+++
writing new private key to './../nginx/ssl/server.key'
-----
Signature ok
subject=/C=US/ST=New York/L=Rochester/O=End Point/OU=Testing Domain/emailAddress=your-administrative-address@your-awesome-existing-domain.com/CN=localhost
Getting CA Private Key
Enter pass phrase for /home/alexzeitler/ssl/rootCA.key:
```

But Chrome 58 still refuses the certificate:

```
This server could not prove that it is localhost; its security certificate is from [missing_subjectAltName]. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.
```

This is the output of `openssl req -in ../nginx/ssl/server.csr -noout -text`:

```
Certificate Request:
    Data:
        Version: 0 (0x0)
        Subject: C=US, ST=New York, L=Rochester, O=End Point, OU=Testing Domain/emailAddress=your-administrative-address@your-awesome-existing-domain.com, CN=localhost
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:cf:ec:6d:54:6e:db:e0:9c:cd:17:c2:dd:bf:81:
                    1e:52:bb:62:27:04:f3:13:8e:01:69:47:fa:93:92:
                    57:b3:77:be:51:87:9b:c8:40:f1:28:de:df:cb:d2:
                    fd:87:fb:00:a1:c4:17:30:4c:9a:fd:e0:b6:d0:8c:
                    a0:c9:01:f4:71:5f:63:ee:6d:4c:5a:b4:4d:ca:60:
                    d4:0b:dc:6f:c1:2b:62:95:44:76:ec:45:bf:cb:39:
                    4a:0a:e4:f7:84:56:d0:1b:11:2c:e7:a8:b6:f6:bc:
                    46:89:bb:4b:44:3c:7d:9d:d8:cc:75:4c:4c:72:15:
                    b4:58:77:9b:38:61:72:4c:b2:45:55:a2:34:06:aa:
                    4c:9d:54:cb:a4:bf:58:26:88:11:81:17:a3:52:ab:
                    c8:38:f7:c5:55:78:af:d3:be:3f:70:95:79:d9:79:
                    10:45:5f:e9:10:e9:56:6f:b5:fa:b9:36:2e:c8:40:
                    c5:fa:86:66:12:82:ec:ab:45:75:54:ec:93:40:9f:
                    d1:cc:8f:18:31:8b:62:1c:20:da:6e:19:17:89:c5:
                    6f:c5:b9:23:a0:86:6e:70:f9:2a:b1:e3:87:dc:a2:
                    57:99:16:05:d4:85:01:43:34:48:d5:b4:39:35:63:
                    46:81:d2:f1:b8:66:e2:21:31:c3:8a:02:f7:8f:a9:
                    b4:8b
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        Attributes:
        Requested Extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:localhost
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         60:d7:11:95:45:9b:b6:35:ed:b7:31:2b:14:5d:c7:57:bb:cd:
         fc:3b:c4:97:01:aa:46:4c:58:9b:f8:4c:44:e2:12:46:2d:69:
         5f:95:10:02:fd:79:e1:30:cb:a9:f9:41:b2:a7:b6:fa:e3:2f:
         e9:c6:7c:3e:3a:b1:db:64:b9:6e:ab:a1:98:82:0c:df:cf:b5:
         e9:7f:17:f0:87:c9:09:15:ab:c8:9b:a2:d8:b3:37:a8:13:2e:
         05:f5:ab:18:4c:cf:d9:6d:d0:05:c4:90:b5:0e:a5:c2:24:6d:
         12:fb:e1:64:5c:d0:6f:5a:86:a3:d2:1f:b8:73:12:1e:39:28:
         a9:50:a4:88:fb:e6:24:95:17:43:76:22:7d:57:48:af:84:36:
         66:30:d8:3b:88:3b:4c:c5:44:fc:92:75:16:b6:9a:22:4b:cf:
         b2:9b:19:e2:15:d4:9c:04:85:8d:7a:59:f7:13:7c:be:d4:4f:
         c5:d8:02:79:ab:98:3f:91:0e:da:ba:8b:68:01:d3:71:cb:f0:
         55:22:fe:f8:55:41:ef:ac:f4:55:48:06:ce:75:ba:33:5c:b2:
         7b:f3:a7:b4:c3:ec:c0:52:ec:e1:56:64:84:cb:fa:a1:ca:0c:
         c0:c3:87:e4:f4:c1:5b:8b:92:00:26:9d:a8:6b:35:58:1f:ad:
         9e:91:ba:5b
```

Thus, the `Subject Alternative Name` information seems to exist in the csr.

On the other hand `openssl x509 -text -in ../nginx/ssl/server.crt -noout` outputs:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Serial Number: 17237690484651272010 (0xef38942aa5c5274a)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, ST=New York, L=Rochester, O=End Point, CN=localhost/emailAddress=your-administrative-address@your-awesome-existing-domain.com
        Validity
            Not Before: Apr 23 15:42:28 2017 GMT
            Not After : Sep  5 15:42:28 2018 GMT
        Subject: C=US, ST=New York, L=Rochester, O=End Point, OU=Testing Domain/emailAddress=your-administrative-address@your-awesome-existing-domain.com, CN=localhost
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:af:ee:7c:7a:2c:3c:5c:a6:57:ce:81:cf:22:49:
                    3c:d3:c4:6d:3a:71:a8:c7:cf:04:cc:68:4a:e6:03:
                    7c:9d:9d:49:c7:4f:8e:33:09:5b:73:9b:a0:21:51:
                    27:c6:e6:d0:ac:f5:5e:1d:4f:f8:60:9f:a1:50:1e:
                    dd:1f:bc:20:44:6f:42:c8:de:2a:6f:04:b7:21:aa:
                    cb:82:18:5e:fa:d8:68:5d:e5:c6:a0:cb:39:e3:91:
                    60:99:3f:ae:63:ab:9c:23:e9:03:0c:ca:10:23:8f:
                    76:e1:5c:55:10:b7:e1:e7:aa:e7:24:4d:49:ff:d0:
                    c7:67:f6:8a:1d:36:12:15:49:2d:33:c9:39:d4:3f:
                    7f:b6:a5:9e:ac:b5:55:75:aa:bc:7f:f4:c2:85:b4:
                    18:f1:76:3c:5e:a3:df:47:00:1c:e6:ac:d5:3c:f3:
                    ac:ff:f2:f0:7a:43:3f:63:bd:77:86:ea:3f:e5:35:
                    04:fa:3c:2a:0c:34:b5:36:ee:a0:b2:50:f9:08:31:
                    b8:76:27:af:c7:c6:5a:af:52:07:6f:c3:d6:6c:97:
                    6b:9b:cb:cd:c7:01:4f:33:7e:2f:09:06:b0:71:1a:
                    9a:9f:30:d4:c3:67:89:15:dc:df:ad:68:44:54:29:
                    26:d0:ca:8e:f6:eb:dd:f3:1a:74:63:89:b4:c5:72:
                    82:af
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         42:f7:c4:1e:47:dc:e7:81:3a:b0:83:a8:fd:51:53:32:f7:80:
         76:b4:ec:a8:44:17:5a:18:29:68:9f:14:4a:1c:35:87:3e:7a:
         13:95:0c:8b:5b:2f:f9:f0:42:56:51:9c:a9:9f:7f:77:45:7d:
         6c:1d:1c:39:75:99:4a:c5:22:c4:d9:1d:11:bb:bf:7d:56:7b:
         a7:18:fc:2a:c3:32:c1:72:3a:17:0e:1d:27:f1:f3:b6:72:91:
         5d:38:64:6c:98:03:8b:17:88:ce:2c:a2:dc:2a:86:a0:e8:23:
         e8:07:79:ac:05:62:b1:17:10:84:82:02:23:4a:10:9a:2a:b3:
         9c:5d:05:71:31:43:f3:28:4e:28:bd:31:49:21:1f:39:b0:6b:
         39:27:1c:1a:8e:b8:92:e9:e7:76:a2:e7:3e:6c:ba:fc:56:f1:
         78:85:3f:68:ea:db:50:88:b4:8a:fc:ea:73:04:4b:8a:54:86:
         5e:0d:fc:b4:70:72:c9:5a:c7:cf:cb:19:e2:9a:b9:af:c6:3e:
         55:06:1c:7c:62:44:b3:e6:57:2b:0f:cc:33:9e:28:5f:62:85:
         05:27:4c:f0:de:6c:d6:fb:e4:de:2f:41:99:34:b2:b1:7d:12:
         b6:d6:96:a5:4b:c4:49:6b:49:bf:c5:86:e6:3c:3e:f3:e3:ef:
         a9:d3:21:5e
```

The `.crt` doesn't contain the `Subject Alternative Name`.

Comment: Your still going to have to trust the certificate by adding it to the certificate store have you done that?

Comment: I added the `rootCA.crt` to the trusted CA certs in Chrome (on Ubuntu)

Comment: Firefox - not enforcing subjectAltName - accepts the cert, by the way.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

While reading the [documentation](http://wiki.cacert.org/FAQ/subjectAltName) for `subjectAltName`, I noticed, that my certificate has shown `Version: 1` while the documentation show `Version: 3`.

To get a `Version 3` certificate, I specified the `-extfile` option:

```
sudo openssl x509 -req -in ./../nginx/ssl/${filename}.csr -CA ~/ssl/rootCA.pem -CAkey ~/ssl/rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out ./../nginx/ssl/${filename}.crt -days 500 -sha256 -extfile v3.ext
```

`v3.ext` looks like this:

```
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = localhost
```

When running `openssl x509 -text -in ../nginx/ssl/server.crt -noout` again, the certificate now also contains the `Subject Alternative Name` section:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 17237690484651272016 (0xef38942aa5c52750)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, ST=New York, L=Rochester, O=End Point, CN=localhost/your-administrative-address@your-awesome-existing-domain.com
        Validity
            Not Before: Apr 23 16:07:38 2017 GMT
            Not After : Sep  5 16:07:38 2018 GMT
        Subject: C=US, ST=New York, L=Rochester, O=End Point, OU=Testing Domain/emailAddress=your-administrative-address@your-awesome-existing-domain.com, CN=localhost
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:b2:e3:bd:ed:28:04:85:ea:75:ee:d2:82:e1:eb:
                    f5:5f:7f:cf:7e:cb:70:de:86:9f:75:7c:f3:71:e7:
                    da:16:fb:bc:1f:89:bc:47:08:77:ca:33:20:f1:c1:
                    9e:e3:20:8d:89:14:7e:c1:0a:12:d2:59:24:56:9b:
                    77:90:5f:69:d1:a5:f1:00:38:93:1b:a7:75:f1:33:
                    e2:da:dc:32:a9:0a:85:7d:9a:20:81:ca:20:ee:86:
                    ce:e2:a0:52:d2:ab:11:34:e5:52:99:3a:81:c6:9f:
                    6b:0f:6a:02:2b:38:a6:84:c9:ba:fa:9b:ef:0a:89:
                    22:4b:79:86:3c:bd:44:a5:54:fb:cf:4d:8b:d1:44:
                    03:35:22:de:69:77:c8:fa:4d:c6:01:25:08:9f:4d:
                    a9:79:7a:aa:ca:03:b6:e4:51:57:22:27:5f:a7:12:
                    11:f3:e6:00:29:f6:58:be:2c:aa:09:e4:06:45:d9:
                    3f:75:a7:f0:75:bd:2b:a6:bb:6d:ad:93:bb:b9:1d:
                    d7:75:39:4e:9b:1d:0e:39:cc:17:74:88:f7:e2:b7:
                    85:12:96:e0:cb:42:56:d0:11:e0:84:86:e5:14:a5:
                    f2:6d:43:5d:f9:59:ae:61:7f:01:ae:95:b8:92:27:
                    1d:1c:02:d7:ad:fb:ee:f6:25:38:60:c8:41:20:17:
                    80:69
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:5A:8D:89:64:BD:F2:3E:C2:D7:7B:BE:17:84:F4:29:E8:C5:32:35:34

            X509v3 Basic Constraints:
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Key Usage:
                Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:localhost
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         27:1d:d6:84:50:33:d2:ff:b1:06:9b:fa:f1:40:7d:47:11:bc:
         f7:80:fd:26:87:0e:91:9f:14:be:1f:1d:9b:32:d1:fb:d6:8d:
         af:30:8a:88:38:8c:1c:bf:77:98:8e:cd:06:48:82:fa:09:b9:
         3c:0d:38:c4:a0:da:b7:4d:f5:81:5f:5a:76:04:61:f8:c2:1a:
         17:ad:56:7c:72:ba:f6:65:7f:7f:e7:5e:b2:34:ba:13:23:57:
         84:f1:c5:ca:dd:5b:55:69:95:71:44:4a:30:53:61:5c:ad:47:
         d8:9c:d5:a2:1b:18:2d:e1:19:35:3e:3f:b2:7e:fd:bf:f3:d0:
         45:dc:f5:57:f0:1b:cd:70:1b:e0:34:de:27:98:89:b4:a5:25:
         a5:6c:29:c3:89:a6:a5:c5:4d:f5:45:3b:47:8e:13:45:23:07:
         5e:d6:59:0d:96:c6:a3:f0:c5:3d:ee:a8:ad:36:96:43:13:a1:
         b8:55:f6:c7:10:7e:8f:5d:09:ef:61:17:2a:9c:3b:50:28:c8:
         e3:8d:a6:34:06:50:d4:3e:d5:17:ea:7d:31:97:d3:ee:df:b5:
         23:66:5e:22:b7:e4:fa:36:4f:9a:d5:f0:a3:f9:b4:2b:27:02:
         0b:41:94:d1:a1:f7:1b:2c:7e:74:e6:14:c3:b5:67:15:d2:ca:
         02:77:57:a6
```

I also created [a blog post](https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/Fixing-Chrome-missing_subjectAltName-selfsigned-cert-openssl/).

If you want to add `127.0.0.1`, you must write:

```
[alt_names]
IP.1 = 127.0.0.1
```

If you add `DNS.1 = 127.0.0.1` Chrome will return a `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`.

Thanks to @Robar for pointing this out in the comments.

Comment: Hi, first thanks for this great blog post! I took me one work day to figure out how to add IP addresses to the [alt_name]. So if someone wants to add 127.0.0.1, he must write:
```[alt_name]
IP.1 = 127.0.0.1
```
If you add `DNS.1 =  127.0.0.1` chrome will return a `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`. 
You could add this to your answer, this would save other devs a lot of time if they have the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - I tried this as well but did not mention it. Updated the answer.

Comment: *"If you add DNS.1 = 127.0.0.1 chrome will return a ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID"* - That almost sounds like a Chrome bug. As far as I know, an IP address listed in the SAN has nothing to do with a CN.

Comment: One addition for cross browser compatibility.

IE wants `DNS` entry and chrome `IP`. To make the certificate work on both I had to add the following to subject alt names:

`DNS.1       = localhost`, `DNS.2       = 127.0.0.1`, `IP.1       = 127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 8):

In Windows, save this script in your SSL folder as makeCert.bat.  The self-signed certificate it makes will satisfy Chrome ver 58+ requirement for SAN (Subject Alternative Name).

This script will create these files:  example.cnf, example.crt, example.key

```
@echo off

REM IN YOUR SSL FOLDER, SAVE THIS FILE AS: makeCert.bat
REM AT COMMAND LINE IN YOUR SSL FOLDER, RUN: makecert
REM IT WILL CREATE THESE FILES: example.cnf, example.crt, example.key
REM IMPORT THE .crt FILE INTO CHROME Trusted Root Certification Authorities
REM REMEMBER TO RESTART APACHE OR NGINX AFTER YOU CONFIGURE FOR THESE FILES

REM PLEASE UPDATE THE FOLLOWING VARIABLES FOR YOUR NEEDS.
SET HOSTNAME=example
SET DOT=com
SET COUNTRY=US
SET STATE=KS
SET CITY=Olathe
SET ORGANIZATION=IT
SET ORGANIZATION_UNIT=IT Department
SET EMAIL=webmaster@%HOSTNAME%.%DOT%

(
echo [req]
echo default_bits = 2048
echo prompt = no
echo default_md = sha256
echo x509_extensions = v3_req
echo distinguished_name = dn
echo:
echo [dn]
echo C = %COUNTRY%
echo ST = %STATE%
echo L = %CITY%
echo O = %ORGANIZATION%
echo OU = %ORGANIZATION_UNIT%
echo emailAddress = %EMAIL%
echo CN = %HOSTNAME%.%DOT%
echo:
echo [v3_req]
echo subjectAltName = @alt_names
echo:
echo [alt_names]
echo DNS.1 = *.%HOSTNAME%.%DOT%
echo DNS.2 = %HOSTNAME%.%DOT%
)>%HOSTNAME%.cnf

openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout %HOSTNAME%.key -days 3560 -out %HOSTNAME%.crt -config %HOSTNAME%.cnf
```

Comment: Still have problem common name invalid while import certification to Chrome.

Comment: ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Answer (score 0):

Stuff like this always goes in `/usr/local/bin`.

I got this from https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/Fixing-Chrome-missing_subjectAltName-selfsigned-cert-openssl/

```
#! /bin/bash

mkdir /tmp/scert 2>/dev/null
rm -r /tmp/scert/* 2>/dev/null

if [ $# -ne 1 ];
then
        echo "Usage: scert <name>"
        exit
fi

if [ -e "/etc/ssl/private/$1.key" ];
then
        echo "/etc/ssl/private/$1.key already exists"
        exit
fi

if [ -e "/etc/ssl/certs/$1.crt" ];
then
        echo "/etc/ssl/certs/$1.crt already exists"
        exit
fi

if [ -e "/etc/ssl/certs/$1.pem" ];
then
        echo "/etc/ssl/certs/$1.pem already exists"
        exit
fi

echo "[req]" > /tmp/scert/tmp.cnf
echo "default_bits = 2048" >> /tmp/scert/tmp.cnf
echo "prompt = no" >> /tmp/scert/tmp.cnf
echo "default_md = sha256" >> /tmp/scert/tmp.cnf
echo "distinguished_name = dn" >> /tmp/scert/tmp.cnf
echo "" >> /tmp/scert/tmp.cnf
echo "[dn]" >> /tmp/scert/tmp.cnf
echo "C=US" >> /tmp/scert/tmp.cnf
echo "ST=New York" >> /tmp/scert/tmp.cnf
echo "L=Rochester" >> /tmp/scert/tmp.cnf
echo "O=$1" >> /tmp/scert/tmp.cnf
echo "OU=Testing Domain" >> /tmp/scert/tmp.cnf
echo "emailAddress=spam@uce.gov" >> /tmp/scert/tmp.cnf
echo "CN = localhost" >> /tmp/scert/tmp.cnf

echo "authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer" > /tmp/scert/tmp.ext
echo "basicConstraints=CA:FALSE" >> /tmp/scert/tmp.ext
echo "keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment" >> /tmp/scert/tmp.ext
echo "subjectAltName = @alt_names" >> /tmp/scert/tmp.ext
echo "" >> /tmp/scert/tmp.ext
echo "[alt_names]" >> /tmp/scert/tmp.ext
echo "DNS.1 = localhost" >> /tmp/scert/tmp.ext

openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:x -out /tmp/scert/tmp.pass.key 2048
openssl rsa -passin pass:x -in "/tmp/scert/tmp.pass.key" -out "/tmp/scert/tmp.key"

openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key /tmp/scert/tmp.key  -subj "/C=US/ST=New York/L=Rochester/O=$1/OU=Testing Domain/CN=localhost" -sha256 -days 1024 -out /tmp/scert/$1.pem

openssl req -new -sha256 -nodes -out /tmp/scert/tmp.csr -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /tmp/scert/$1.key -config <( cat /tmp/scert/tmp.cnf )

openssl x509 -req -in /tmp/scert/tmp.csr -CA /tmp/scert/$1.pem -CAkey /tmp/scert/tmp.key -CAcreateserial -out /tmp/scert/$1.crt -days 500 -sha256 -extfile /tmp/scert/tmp.ext

if [ -e "/tmp/scert/$1.key" ];
then
        sudo cp /tmp/scert/$1.key /etc/ssl/private
        sudo chown root:ssl-cert /etc/ssl/private/$1.key
        sudo chmod 640 /etc/ssl/private/$1.key
        ls -al /etc/ssl/private/$1.key
else
        echo "ERROR: /tmp/scert/$1.key not found"
fi

if [ -e "/tmp/scert/$1.crt" ];
then
        sudo cp /tmp/scert/$1.crt /etc/ssl/certs
        sudo chown root:root /etc/ssl/certs/$1.crt
        sudo chmod 755 /etc/ssl/certs/$1.crt
        ls -al /etc/ssl/certs/$1.crt
else
        echo "ERROR: /tmp/scert/$1.crt not found"
fi

if [ -e "/tmp/scert/$1.pem" ];
then
        sudo cp /tmp/scert/$1.pem /etc/ssl/certs
        sudo chown root:root /etc/ssl/certs/$1.pem
        sudo chmod 755 /etc/ssl/certs/$1.pem
        ls -al /etc/ssl/certs/$1.pem
else
        echo "ERROR: /tmp/scert/$1.pem not found"
fi

rm -r /tmp/scert/* 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated [STWilson](https://superuser.com/users/529007/stwilson)'s batch file to remove the COM stuff since localhost doesn't really have that and I want a self-signed localhost SSL certificate for development. I also added a few additional files like a .pfx and .pem.key file.

```
@echo off

REM IN YOUR SSL FOLDER, SAVE THIS FILE AS: makeCert.bat
REM AT COMMAND LINE IN YOUR SSL FOLDER, RUN: makecert
REM IT WILL CREATE THESE FILES: example.cnf, example.crt, example.key
REM IMPORT THE .crt FILE INTO CHROME Trusted Root Certification Authorities
REM REMEMBER TO RESTART APACHE OR NGINX AFTER YOU CONFIGURE FOR THESE FILES

REM PLEASE UPDATE THE FOLLOWING VARIABLES FOR YOUR NEEDS.
SET HOSTNAME=example
SET COUNTRY=US
SET STATE=KS
SET CITY=Olathe
SET ORGANIZATION=IT
SET ORGANIZATION_UNIT=IT Department
SET EMAIL=emailhere@somesite.com

(
echo [req]
echo default_bits = 2048
echo prompt = no
echo default_md = sha256
echo x509_extensions = v3_req
echo distinguished_name = dn
echo:
echo [dn]
echo C = %COUNTRY%
echo ST = %STATE%
echo L = %CITY%
echo O = %ORGANIZATION%
echo OU = %ORGANIZATION_UNIT%
echo emailAddress = %EMAIL%
echo CN = %HOSTNAME%
echo:
echo [v3_req]
echo subjectAltName = @alt_names
echo:
echo [alt_names]
echo DNS.1 = *.%HOSTNAME%
echo DNS.2 = %HOSTNAME%
)>%HOSTNAME%.cnf

REM MAKE THE .key .crt AND .cnf FILES
openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout %HOSTNAME%.key -days 3560 -out %HOSTNAME%.crt -config %HOSTNAME%.cnf

REM MAKE THE .pfx FILE
openssl pkcs12 -export -out %HOSTNAME%.pfx -inkey %HOSTNAME%.key -in %HOSTNAME%.crt

REM MAKE THE .pem.key FILE
openssl rsa -in %HOSTNAME%.key -outform PEM -out %HOSTNAME%.pem.key
```

Comment: ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID